# Protractor tests in Angular: how to check variable in scope without ng-bind and ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, bdd, cucumberjs

how to check variable in scope without ng-bind and ng-model ?

```
<span ng-if="user.code === 'YELLOW'">
    <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-circle-remove text-danger"></span> Yellow
</span>
<span ng-if="user.code === 'GREEN'">
    <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-circle-exclamation-mark text-warning"></span> Green
</span>
```

I would like to check the user.code with protractor

With ng-bind and ng-model it doesn't work

```
browser.expect(element(by.binding('user.code')).getText()).to.eventually.equal('');
```

or

```
browser.expect(element(by.model('user.code')).getAttribute('value')).to.eventually.equal('');
```

Error :

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.binding("user.code")
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.model("user.code")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not be testing that kind of stuff in protractor. You should write your tests from the perspective of the user.

However, if you want to test that use `evaluate`. Get a reference to a DOM element and then call evaluate:

```
// Choose a DOM element bound to a scope that contains the value you
// want to test
expect($('span').evaluate('user.code')).toBe('some value');
```

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.evaluate

Answer (score 1):

### First solution

If you can locate your element through CSS selector.

```
$('.glyphicons-circle-remove').isPresent(); // For user.code == 'YELLOW'
$('.glyphicons-circle-exclamation-mark').isPresent(); // For user.code == 'GREEN'
```

### Hacky way

Work only If you are using `ng-if`

```
$('[ng-if="user.code === \'YELLOW\'"]').isPresent(); // For user.code == 'YELLOW'
$('[ng-if="user.code === \'GREEN\'"]').isPresent(); // For user.code == 'GREEN'
```

Since the element is only presenting when condition of `ng-if` satified. So you can also do this.

**NOTE**:
 `.isPresent()` because `ng-if` will remove the element from DOM. 
If you are using `ng-show` you will need to use `.isDisplayed()` instead (*this does not work for second solution*).

Comment: Yes, but I have several glyphicons on my web page

Comment: More more CSS selector details or use the second solution that I updated in the answer. It is dirty but it will sure work.